# Any way to tell g++ to use another binary for compiling?

Tags: linux, g++, compiler-flags

This question may sound a little absurd. Facts:

1. I have a program written in C++.
2. It uses lot of in-house libs.
3. I don't have read permission to the libs.
4. So I have to build with a given tool which does have access to the lib headers and archives.
5. Stuck on gcc 4.3
6. I have a local build of gcc 4.5
7. I want g++ to use my local g++ instead of the old version.

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: Do you call the local build by the path, or just type `g++`?

Comment: I just call it via a script. And the builder runs under a different user. Therefor, I can't do anything by changing my environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path of the compiler instead of invoking it without specifying the path.

Comment: You can also edit your .bashrc and put something like 
export PATH=/home/usr/gcc4.5:$PATH so that you always default to this compiler path.

Answer (score 0):

Many configure scripts accept the CC environment variable:

`export CC=/usr/bin/gcc44` for example. If you have a configure script, try `./configure --help` to see if it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have g++ in your ~/bin folder, could you add

`export PATH=~/bin:$PATH`

to your shell's .profile file (.bash_profile for bash).  Then when you log in again and do `which g++` it should show your local version of g++.